# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Warning happen when i updating my component from react 14 to 15

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Typeahead`.
    in Typeahead (created by Search)
    in div (created by Search)
    in Search (created by Home)
    in Home (created by RouterContext)
    in div (created by App)
    in App (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router
    in Provider
```

How i rectify this issue

Comment: can you show the component code ?

Comment: seems like an `import` issue. you should do `import component from 'path'` or `import {component} from 'path' ` depending whether it was exported default or not. but again, with no code samples we can't realy be sure

Comment: Thanks a lot , Issue fixed